# Convergent sequences must have bounded range?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently reading Baby Rudin and I am having trouble understanding why convergent sequences must have a bounded range. Specifically, I am thinking of the following counterexample: $f(n)=1/(n-1)$
At $n=1$, this sequence diverges, but at infinity, it "converges" to zero. Any insight into the above theorem and my "counterexample" would be appreciated. Also, I apologize for the lack of $\LaTeX$. I am doing this from my phone.

Comment: When we talk about a sequence converging or diverging we are always talking about the limit as $n$ goes to infinity. Also your example would have to start at $n$ equals $2$

Comment: Thank you Foobaz John. So the sequence written isn't defined at n=1, so it doesn't make sense to talk about what happens there. I appreciate your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "sequence" does not diverge at n=1, it is simply not defined at that point, so your domain would be $\mathbb{N} \backslash \{1\}$.
If you say that something diverges you mean that it "tends towards" infinity and not that it actually "is infinity" (whatever that's supposed to mean).

The theorem is easily seen, as you can not "reach infinity" in finitely many steps, but as you go high enough in your domain, eventually you'll have to stay "near" your convergent point.

I hope I'm not to vague here, but I thought as you already have a proof in your Rudin, that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I needed that the sequence is not defined at n=1. I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

The terms have to be (well) defined, that's not the case with your 'first term', $f(1)$.

You can always split the terms of a sequence into a *finite first part* (say the first $k$ terms) and the *"tail"* (all the others).

If a sequence converges, it has a limit $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Because it converges, we know there is a number $N$ such that all the terms $a_i$ are closer to $L$ than any $\varepsilon$ we want, as long as $i>N$ (definition!).

In this way, you can split all the terms into the first $N$ (this a finite number of terms and thus bounded) and all the other terms, which are bounded below by $L-\varepsilon$ and bounded above by $L+\varepsilon$. Hence all the terms are finite and the range of the whole sequence is bounded.